# How to store different types in a column?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I am a novice programmer currently working on how to store PostgreSQL column types in a table column. Specifically, I would like to create a table with a column named 'type' that stores one of the following types: `boolean`, `integer`, `text` and `enum`. Conceptually, however, I would like a user to store which values (s)he would like to use. An integer, a piece of text, or a list of options should all be possible. See the sample table below.

```
id    |    type                             | default value
---------------------------------------------------------------
1     |    integer                          |        5
2     |    boolean                          |        
3     |    enum("red", "blue", "yellow")    |       red
```

The last case confuses me. With my limited knowledge I know that creating a table with a column named `type` with type `enum("boolean", "integer", "text", "enum")` is possible, but I don't see how that allows for the last case in the sample table. It seems like this only allows for a type `enum`, but in that case I cannot specify a default value, such as `red`, because red is not listed in the options of the `enum` type.

I am left with two questions:

1. On creating the table, what type do I give the column named `type`?
2. How do I store the third record in the sample table, such that I can also store a default value and such that I can still check whether the default value is actually appropriate for the chosen type?

Any answer or help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: No. this is very very very very bad design. Don't do it. Turn around and try something else. Please don't implement this. AHHHH! STAHP!

Comment: Haha, have a look at my second comment to Kamil's answer. That should clarify my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing/mixing a lot of different things.

**Regarding enum type**

You can declare a column of a table to be of [enumerated type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html). For this you need to define the type:

```
CREATE TYPE my_color_enum AS ENUM ( 'red', 'blue', 'yellow' );
```

Then use it in table just like any other type:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( column1 my_color_enum );
```

If you need to assign a default value to `column1` it only lets you define a default value that exists in your `ENUM` type, so for example while this **is valid**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( column1 my_color_enum default 'red');
```

This **is not** and will yield an error:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( column1 my_color_enum default 'green' );
```

Because `"green"` value is not present in your type. The error message will look something like this (this is a loose translation, not exact error message):

> Invalid input value for enum my_color_enum: "green"

**Storing different datatypes in one column**

This seems like a bad design, but if you really need it, and would rather avoid `text` datatype and then casting back and forth, you could use `json`, `jsonb` and so forth...

*It will come to bite you if you decide to have a lookup table which stores data types.*

Comment: Hi Kamil! Thanks for replying. Your explanation is absolutely clear to me. Downside is that I indeed want to store different type names in one column. Given your answer: If I were to choose for a column with name `type` and type `text`, and insert values in the column such as `"text"`, `"boolean"` and `"enum('red', 'blue', 'yellow')"`, would it then still be possible to check if a given default value, say "red", is a value present in the string "enum('red', 'blue', 'yellow')"?

Comment: I feel like you are mixing up column types with column values. Why would you store values that are names of datatypes inside a column?

Comment: Because I am writing a piece of software that allows a user to dynamically add a column to a table. The current software has predefined table columns. I ask a user to specify a name for the new table column and type of values the new column should hold. An example is that a product can have a color (new table column name) that is either red, blue or yellow. I keep track of the dynamically added columns by the table I am currently designing. A record in this table (of this example) is then (name, type, default) VALUES ('color', 'enum(red, blue, yellow)', '').

Comment: Ok. That clarifies things. If you have an input field in application layer with default value and you need to check whether it is within the enum he's just chosen, you could add another column to your table with type `text[]` and store all the possible values in there and then compare it in the application. Or if you'd like less elegant approach, you could parse that text with enum datatype to look for a substring in it.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. And thanks, that helps!